# Taking scanner input and outputting min and max

Tags: java, for-loop, input, java.util.scanner

so I'm trying to find the min, max, and average number of the numbers input. Everything works fine, although I do not want input less than 0 or greater than 100. When I input a number less than 0 or greater than 100 it still records it as the min/max. I do not want this! How would I not take input that is less than 0 or greater than 100?
Thanks!

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExamGrades {

public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in );

        int number = 0;
        double total = 0;
        int minimum;
        int maximum = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the first integer: ");

        number = scan.nextInt();
        minimum=number;
        total += number;

        for(int i = 2; i<11; i++){

            if(number<0 || number >100){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number: ");
                number = scan.nextInt();
                i--;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Please enter integer " + i + ":");
                number = scan.nextInt();
                total += number;

            if(number<minimum)
                minimum = number;
            if(number>maximum)
                maximum = number;
            }
        }

        DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
        System.out.println("The minimum is: " + minimum);
        System.out.println("The maximum is: " + maximum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + oneDecimalPlace.format((total) / 10.0 ));

    }
}
```

Comment: My approach is only slightly different than yours (I don't back up in the for-loop, I just keep them in their own loop until they enter a valid number). Let me know if you don't want that change. It's much more simple though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you entered `5` for integer one, then `102` for the second integer. What's going to happen? Well before you entered `102`, `number` was `5`, so it will go into the `else` block.

It'll say:

`Please enter integer 2:`

then you type: `102`

So then what? Well the next piece of code is:

`number = scan.nextInt();` and then it goes through the if-statements right below it to determine if it's a maximum. Nothing is stopping it.

Try this code instead of your loop:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the first integer: ");

number = scan.nextInt();

// keep them in a loop until they enter a valid number
while (number < 0 || number > 100) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number: ");
    number = scan.nextInt();
}

// after they entered a valid number, add it to the series
minimum = number;
total += number;

for(int i = 2; i < 11; i++) {

    System.out.println("Please enter integer " + i + ":");
    number = scan.nextInt();

    // keep them in a loop until they enter a valid number
    while (number < 0 || number > 100) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number: ");
        number = scan.nextInt();
    }

    // after they entered a valid number, add it to the series

    total += number;

    if(number<minimum)
        minimum = number;
    if(number>maximum)
        maximum = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**problem:**

```
if(number<0 || number >100)
```

It will return `false` when `number` is **100** or **0** thus accepting it and executing you else block.

Is `100>100` answer `false` because they are equal, not greater than the other

**solution:**

```
if(number<1 || number >99)
```

EDit:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in );

        int number = 0;
        double total = 0;
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the first integer: ");

        number = scan.nextInt();
        if(number>1 && number <99)
        {
        minimum=number;
        total += number;
        }
        for(int i = 2; i<11; i++){

            if(number<1 || number >99){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number: ");
                number = scan.nextInt();
                i--;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Please enter integer " + i + ":");
                number = scan.nextInt();
                total += number;

                if(number>1 && number <99)
                {
                     if(number<minimum)
                         minimum = number;
                     if(number>maximum)
                         maximum = number;
                }

            }
        }

        DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
        System.out.println("The minimum is: " + minimum);
        System.out.println("The maximum is: " + maximum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + oneDecimalPlace.format((total) / 10.0 ));


}
```

Comment: No, I understand that. That isn't my problem. My problem is that if I input a number less than 0 or greater than 100 it will output those numbers as my min/max instead of the min/max inbetween 0 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example.Exceptions are not handled so put a Try-catch to String to Integer Conversion If you want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Numbers{
    public static void main(String x[]){
        Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
        int Total=0,Max=0,Min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<10;){
            System.out.print("Enter Number :");         
            int NumberOne=Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());//Put a Try catch If needed
            if(NumberOne>0&&NumberOne<100){
                Total+=NumberOne;
                Max=(Max>NumberOne)?Max:NumberOne;
                Min=(Min<NumberOne)?Min:NumberOne;
                i++;
            }else{
                System.out.print("Number Invalid");         
            }
        }
        DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
        System.out.println("The minimum is: " + Min);
        System.out.println("The maximum is: " + Max);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + oneDecimalPlace.format((Total) / 10.0 ));
    }

}
```